# compass sprite is not working in ie8 and ie7

Tags: compass-sass, css-sprites

I am using compass to make image sprites. It successfully works on modern browser but its not working in ie 8 and ie7. I am really new to compass I just used some simple mixin to display the sprite.

`@include spr-sprite("arrow-step"); height:30px; width:30px;`

Is there anything am missing with it. Thanks in advance for the repliers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh god. I was using sprite under the selectors like `h1:not(#foo)` which is not supported in ie 8 and ie 7. Its solved.