# Compass sprites in IE8

Tags: compass-sass, sprite

I just started using Compass' sprite generator a few days ago and realized that my sprites are not showing up in IE8. I think that I traced my problem back to this previously reported issue: [compass sprite is not working in ie8 and ie7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214604/compass-sprite-is-not-working-in-ie8-and-ie7)

Santosh points out that IE8 breaks when pseudo classes like :not are used.

I can see that my selector is probably breaking because Compass is including the :checked and :before pseudo classes in the selector (from `icons/global/*.png`):

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .btn-checkbox:before, 
input[type="checkbox"].checked + .btn-checkbox:before, 
input[type="radio"]:checked + .btn-checkbox:before,
input[type="radio"].checked + .btn-checkbox:before,
.segmented-checkbox .btn-    checkbox.selected:before
{
  background: url(/assets/rp-icons/global-s67c66a3554.png) no-repeat;
}
```

My question is how do I change the automatically generated selector or split it up so that the whole thing doesn't break in IE8?

This issue was also mentioned here, but the solution is not clear:
https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1193

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:
IE8 can't understand `:checked`, thus making the entire declaration invalid.

You have two options:

#### #1 Make the sprite twice

First use conditional comment to add the class `.ie` to html or body

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> <html class="ie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->
```

First line is 'lower than IE 9', so IE8 or below get class `ie`. The second is 'greater than IE8' so IE9+ and other browsers (note the `<!-->`).

So now split your sprite in two, one for `:checked` and another to `.checked`, importing twice, so the final css is:

```
/*this will be invalid for IE<8, valid for all others*/
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .btn-checkbox:before, 
input[type="radio"]:checked + .btn-checkbox:before,
.segmented-checkbox .btn-checkbox.selected:before
{
  background: url(/assets/rp-icons/global-{hash}.png) no-repeat;
}

/*this would be valid for everyone, but since we added .ie, just IE will apply*/
.ie input[type="checkbox"].checked + .btn-checkbox:before, 
.ie input[type="radio"].checked + .btn-checkbox:before,
.ie .segmented-checkbox .btn-checkbox.selected:before
{
  background: url(/assets/rp-icons/global-{hash}.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Then create a handler with javascript that when the input is clicked, if it is checked you add checked class;

#### #2 Try see if a polyfill will fix for you:

You can try http://selectivizr.com/, it have polyfill for `:checked` on all supported frameworks! so it will make IE8 accept your `:checked`. *Read 'You need to know' at the end of page to know its limitations*